# How to extract .war files in java? ZIP vs JAR

Tags: java, jar, zip, war

I have a web program where I want the user to be able to import a `.war` file and I can extract certain files out of the `.war` file.  I have found two class libraries:  `java.util.zip.*` and `java.util.jar.*`. From what I understand, a WAR file is a special JAR file which is a special ZIP file.  So would it be better to use `java.util.jar`?  If ZIP and JAR files are pretty much the same why is there a need for two different libraries?

Comment: What will you do with the files inside the war file?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you look at the [JarFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) API you'll see that it's a subclass of the [ZipFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) class.

The jar-specific classes mostly just add jar-specific functionality, like direct support for manifest file attributes and so on.

It's OOP "in action"; since jar files are zip files, the jar classes can use zip functionality and provide additional utility.

Comment: Downvotes on correct and accepted answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 147):

WAR file is just a JAR file, to extract it, just issue following jar command –

```
jar -xvf yourWARfileName.war
```

If the jar command is not found, which sometimes happens in the Windows command prompt, then specify full path i.e. in my case it is,

```
 c:\java\jdk-1.7.0\bin\jar -xvf my-file.war
```

Comment: I used this command and extrated .war file.. but all these goes to bin folder.. can u paste the command for choosing extracting location

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830952/extracting-jar-to-specified-directory

Comment: In Java, asked the OP.

Answer (score 19):

Just rename the `.war` into `.jar` and unzip it using `Winrar` (or any other archive manager).

Answer (score 6):

If you using Linux or Ubuntu than you can directly extract data from `.war` file.

A `war` file is just a `jar` file, to extract it, just issue following command using the `jar` program:

```
jar -xvf yourWARfileName.war
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a turn-around and just deploy the application into tomcat server: just copy/paste under the webapps folder.
Once tomcat is started, it will create a folder with the app name and you can access the contents directly

Answer (score 1):

For mac users: in terminal command :

```
unzip yourWARfileName.war
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to unarchive war

```
mkdir mywarfile
cp -r mywarfile.war mywarfile/
cd mywarfile/
jar -xvf mywarfile.war
ls
rm -rf mywarfile.war
```

To cut multiple lines in vi editor, you can use the following steps:

a8350801-7572-4a74-8559-5743fd2a3e86

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, a jar *is* a zip file  (not a special type, but just a plain old zip), so either library could be made to work.  The reasoning is that the average person, seeing a *.zip extension, tends to unzip it.  Since the app server wants it unzipped, a simple rename keeps people from unzipping it simply out of habit. Likewise,  *.war file also should remain uncompressed.

java.util.jar basically just adds additional functionality to java.util.zip with very little extra overhead. Let the java.util.jar be a helper in posting, etc... and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Jar class/package is for specific Jar file mechanisms where there is a manifest that is used by the Jar files in some cases.

The Zip file class/package handles any compressed files that include Jar files, which is a type of compressed file.

The Jar classes thus extend the Zip package classes.