# Extracting jar to specified directory

Tags: java, jar, command

I wanted to extract one of my jars to specified directory using `jar` command line utility.

If I understand this right `-C` option should to the trick but when I try

```
jar xvf myJar.jar -C ./directoryToExtractTo
```

I am getting usage information from my jar utility, so I am doing something wrong.

Is the thing I want achievable with `jar` or do I need to manually move my jar and there invoke

```
jar xvf myJar.jar
```

Comment: I think `-C` is just for adding files.

Comment: Maybe, I thought that it is also for specyfying the output directory.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It's better to do this.

Navigate to the folder structure you require

Use the command

```
jar -xvf  'Path_to_ur_Jar_file'
```

Comment: Of couse I could do this and I agree with out that I can do this, I just wanted to know if i misinterpreted -C option, and it seems that is the case.

Comment: Maybe that's the only way to specify target location via "jar xf".

Comment: If you want it in a single line like I did: `cd /my/path && jar -xvf  'Path_to_ur_Jar_file'`

Answer (score 103):

jars use zip compression so you can use any unzip utility.

Example:

`$ unzip myJar.jar -d ./directoryToExtractTo`

Comment: `unzip myJar.jar -d out-directory` for Xubuntu 12.04.1

Comment: I had issues in the past using zip to create a jar (it is NOT equivalent to using the jar command) but I can't speak for unzipping. My recommendation is to use this at your own risk and favor using the jar command.

Comment: gunzip complains that the jar has more than one entry

Comment: NO issues what so ever on rhel6... why is everything in java so half-baked ??

Comment: What if `unzip` is not on path, as in some distroless container, only `jar` is available...

Answer (score 15):

There is no such option available in jar command itself. Look into [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html):

> -C  dir Temporarily changes directories (cd dir) during execution of the jar command while processing the following inputfiles argument.
>   Its operation is intended to be similar to the -C option of the UNIX
>   tar utility. For example: jar uf foo.jar -C classes bar.class changes
>   to the classes directory and add the bar.class from that directory to
>   foo.jar. The following command, jar uf foo.jar -C classes . -C bin
>   xyz.class changes to the classes directory and adds to foo.jar all
>   files within the classes directory (without creating a classes
>   directory in the jar file), then changes back to the original
>   directory before changing to the bin directory to add xyz.class to
>   foo.jar. If classes holds files bar1 and bar2, then here's what the
>   jar file contains using jar tf foo.jar: META-INF/
>
> META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
>
> bar1
>
> bar2
>
> xyz.class

Answer (score 8):

In case you don't want to change your current working directory, it might be easier to run extract command in a subshell like this.

```
mkdir -p "/path/to/target-dir"
(cd "/path/to/target-dir" && exec jar -xf "/path/to/your/war-file.war")
```

You can then execute this script from any working directory.

[ Thanks to [David Schmitt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786376/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-a-different-working-directory-from-current-from-lin?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for the subshell trick ]

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.

I created a folder then changed into the folder using CD option from command prompt.

Then executed the jar from there.

```
d:\LS\afterchange>jar xvf ..\mywar.war
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up using inside my .bat file. Windows only of course.

```
set CURRENT_DIR=%cd%
mkdir ./directoryToExtractTo
cd ./directoryToExtractTo
jar xvf %CURRENT_DIR%\myJar.jar
cd %CURRENT_DIR%
```

Comment: set CURRENT_DIR=%cd%
mkdir -p directoryToExtractTo
cd "directoryToExtractTo"
jar xvf %CURRENT_DIR%\myJar.jar
cd %CURRENT_DIR%

Answer (score 0):

Current working version as of Oct 2020, updated to use maven-antrun-plugin 3.0.0.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <unzip src="target/shaded-jar/shade-test.jar"
                                   dest="target/unpacked-shade/"/>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit of overkill, but this is something I wanted, so I wrote a Bourne Shell script for it (dependencies on `sed` and `grep`):

```sh
Usage: unjar FILE [DEST]

- DEST must not already exist (won't overwrite existing contents);
  path to DEST will be created.

- If DEST is not provided, defaults to a subdirectory in the current
  working directory that will be named after FILE without the extension.
  Ex: unjar foo.jar  # foo.jar extracted to ./foo

- If DEST is provided, the path will be created and the jar will
  be extracted into it.
  Ex: unjar foo.jar /a/b/c  # foo.jar extracted into /a/b/c
```

The full script is here at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/57bf9dca1951c3d0da9672d9ae8b97c5)