# Java web service other than tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Is there any web service that runs as a jar?

I've already tried using spark but besides from running a jar I need it to be able to render jsp files.

My current scenario is that I have a tomcat(.war) project that depends on another project(.jar) and I want to add some web functionalities to this second project.
However I cannot change it to a .war as one .war project cannot depend on another .war project.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not embed the JAR file you want to enhance into a WAR? (You can also consider other app servers, but I dont see. Separating the web part from the JAR lib is good practice anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm facing a similar issue, and my workaround is less than elegant but I haven't found a better one yet.

To restate the issue:

- ProjectA.war depends on X.class (or more) from Project B.jar
- ProjectB.jar needs to be repackaged as Project B.war

The solution I'm going with:

- Convert ProjectB.jar to ProjectB.war as needed
- Manually extract the ProjectB.jar file from ProjectB.war and cite that extracted .jar as a dependency in ProjectA

(I followed [How to extract .war files in java? ZIP vs JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882745/how-to-extract-war-files-in-java-zip-vs-jar))

Depending on your build system you can also set ProjectB to build both a .war and a .jar for dependency at the same time; I'm using Maven and that's the path I'm eventually going* so that I'm not manually digging out the .jar each time I update ProjectB, and then I'm just going to list that .jar as a dependency for ProjectA.

* = http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html at the bottom of the FAQ, "How do I create a JAR containing the classes in my webapp?"

Comment: Could you point me towards the maven solution? My projects are also maven projects and that seems like a cool solution that would actually help in more places.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at the bottom of this page:

Comment: Well, I fail to not double post: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html it's the bottom of the FAQ, "How do I create a JAR containing the classes in my webapp?"

Answer (score 0):

Put the common code into the jar. (Refactor that code to a new module whithout the front end parts).

Add that jar as a dependency in the wars.

Or if you can afford it, just start migrating to microservices where the "tomcat" is inside the jar and not the other way around.

[For instance using Spring Boot](https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring)

Answer (score 0):

You should not add web functionality on your JAR file. The better solution is to have a JAR library common to your two web services. Also, I recommend spring boot for your second web service because it's easy to use and configure, you could have jar web service on a jiffy (Embedded inside it is tomcat).

Here's a sample:

`+----------+ +----------+
|    WAR   | |  JAR-WS  |
| +-------------------+ |
| |      COMMONS      | |
| +-------------------+ |
+----------+ +----------+`